# Associating 3 Attributes using linear regression or non linear regression in R

Tags: r, rstudio, data-modeling, linear-regression, prediction

I am having 3 variables x, y, z. each contains an equal amount of data say 40 numbers. using linear regression

```
x <- 1:40
y <- 1:40/2
z <- 41:80
```

`model <- lm(x~y)` 
i can associate x and y values can create a data model to predict x values.

`a <- data.frame(x = 52)`

`res <- predict(model, a)`

it will predict y value based on the association. now i can plot the prediction line using the following code

`plot(x, y)`

`plotdata <- cbind(x, predict(model))`

`lines(plotdata[order(x),], col = "red")` .

So my question is if I have three variables x,y,z. how to associate and predict.

```
lm(x~y~z)
```

is not working. plotting can be done by using

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(x,y,z)

model1 <- (x~y+z)

plotdata <- cbind(y,z, predict(model))
lines3d(plotdata[order(y,z),], col = "red")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that + sign is same as "~ "? I mean all three are independent. y+z is same as y~z ?

Comment: depends on what your regression question is. what's your response (or dependent) variable and what's your predictor (independent) variable? Are you interested in multivariate regression or multiple linear regression? Perhaps you should look for some general help on regression first before plunging into the codes.

Comment: yes, i am looking for multivariate regression where I can do regression with not only three but 3 or more variable so that if I give input of one variable it could predict values of other variables. thanks in advance.